# Installing WebApplication scoped feature through code - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I've a WebApplication scoped feature which I need to install through code.

In short, I need to perform

```
stsadm -o installfeature -name MyFeature
```

through code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public void InstallFeature(string name, bool force)
{
  string relativePath = name + @"\feature.xml";
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions.Add(relativePath, Guid.Empty, force);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the code for the [SharePoint Solution Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.